# SignalR Actors or Stateless Services

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm looking into migrating an application to Service Fabric running on Azure. It's a realtime chat-style application using SignalR. I'd like to have an instance of a service running, self-hosting a SignalR hub (via OWIN) for each "affinity group" in which users are communicating. This is so I can avoid having to scale out SignalR with a backplane. I'd like to be able to spin these services up and down as groups of users enter and leave my application. I would expect I could host tens of these services per VM with a typical load of hundreds of users per group.

My idea is that I'd have a service locator that clients connect to initially to discover which service (port) is hosting their group. I would also have a service that spun up an instance of the chat service when the first request for that group came in.

How would I architect this in Service Fabric on Azure so that a) each of the services/actors is accessible with a SignalR client from the internet? and b) I'm only running as many services as necessary to serve `m` active groups out of `n` total groups? The demand for this app is very transient and spiky, so I'm hoping to take advantage of the fact that services are simply processes and can be provisioned in a matter of seconds vs. my current scenario where I have to spin up entire cloud services and wait tens of minutes to handle spikes (at which point it's too late)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do a few things:

- Have a "service manager service" that intercepted initial join requests and created new Service Fabric services on the fly if they didn't already exist OR if they did already exist resolve the service's current location and then return that address to the client

  - Alternatively they could just pass back the internal service name (if you're ok exposing that information) and the client could do the resolution and then connection. To some degree this will depend on how much info you want to expose to the client, whether you can or want to modify it to "know about" Service Fabric, etc.
- The client would then connect to the actual backing service directly
- You would have to come up with some sort of mechanism for the actual chat services to know that there is nobody left and to either delete themselves or to go back through the manager.
- You probably would be best off modeling the chat service as a Reliable Service rather than an actor as the Reliable Services stack allows more flexibility around communication protocols/stacks.